# Method re-create list and dont let me remove elements (C#)

Tags: c#, list, forms, listview, methods

I try to make a programm where you have 2 buttons.

The first one give you a question randomly chosen from a list, the other one give and asnwer, comparing the index of the question list with the index  of the aswer list.

[how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qixC0.png)

After showing the answer I want to delete the element from the question and answer list.

The problem is every time the code runs, re-create both list, I want to delete both elements from the list after showing the answer. I try to use a loop but I cant with methods (or dont know how), any help will be very apreciated.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        superiorText.Text = summonQuestion();
    }
    private void buttonAnswer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        inferiorText.Text = summonAnswer(superiorText.Text);
    }
    static void callList(out List<string> questionList, out List<string> answerList)
    {
        questionList = new List<string> {
        "question 1",
        "question 2",
        "question 3"};

        answerList = new List<string>{
        "answer 1",
        "answer 2",
        "answer 3"};
    }
    static string summonQuestion()
    {
        callList(out List<string> questionList, out List<string> respuestas);
       Random random = new Random();
       return questionList[random.Next(0, questionList.Count)];
    }
    static string summonAnswer(string superiorText)
    {
        callList(out List<string> questionList, out List<string> answerList);
        foreach (string data in questionList)
            {
            if (data == superiorText)
            {
                string answer = answerList[questionList.IndexOf(data)];
                answerList.RemoveAt(questionList.IndexOf(data));
                questionList.Remove(data);
                return answer;
                }
            }
        return "404";
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider using a class with two string properties `Question` and `Answer` and using on list of those objects. Is your question "How do I remove an item from a list" (in which case, look at the docs for `List.Remove` and `List.RemoveAt`). Or, does it have something to do with removing things the next time the program starts

Comment: *The problem is every time the code runs, re-create both list,* - yep SummonQuestion and SummonAnswer call CallList, which does indeed recreate both lists. Perhaps you should move "creating the list" to something that is done once, like the form constructor

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I put the list on a new class, with a contructor who add the elements. When I try to bring it the list in the method happends the same. Probablly its something wrong when I create the list: https://dotnetfiddle.net/SSBGZN I'll continue searching in the direction u told me, thank you!